# Is there any way to have several enumerations with common methods and fiedls but with different values?

Tags: java

In my code, I need a few enumerations that have common fields and methods but different value sets. I know that inheritance does not work with enumerations, but may be there is a trick or a workaround that allows to do something like the following:

```
  enum Parent {
    DUMMY_ITEM("", 0); // Not necessary 

    String otherName;   // Common fields
    int intValue;

    Parent(String otherName, int intValue) { // A common constructor
      this.intValue = intValue;
      this.otherName = otherName; 
    } 

    void setIntValue(int value) { intValue = value; } // Common methods
    int getIntValue()           { return intValue; }
    int calcSomething()         { return intValue * otherName.length(); }
  }

  enum Child1 extends Parent {    // An individual value set 
    // that inherits fields and methods from its parent
    ACTUAL_CHILD1_ITEM1("CHILD1_ITEM1", 3),
    ACTUAL_CHILD1_ITEM2("CHILD1_ITEM2", 2),
    ACTUAL_CHILD1_ITEM3("CHILD1_ITEM3", 1),
  }  

  enum Child2 extends Parent {    // another value set
    // that inherits fields and methods from its parent
    ACTUAL_CHILD2_ITEM1("CHILD2_ITEM1", 1),
    ACTUAL_CHILD2_ITEM2("CHILD2_ITEM2", 2),
    ACTUAL_CHILD2_ITEM3("CHILD2_ITEM3", 3),
  }
```

So that I could write `int i = ACTUAL_CHILD2_ITEM1.getIntValue()`, `int j = ACTUAL_CHILD1_ITEM3.calcSomething()` and so on. It would not be nice to repeat same fields and method in multiple enumerations, while I would like to have different value sets to avoid mess and to get a relevant help from my IDE.

Comment: Use aggregation, not inheritance.  Have each child enum type contain an instance of Parent, and make that instance available with a public method.  If you need polymorphism, have each enum type implement an interface, like `interface ParentContainer { Parent getParent(); }`.

Comment: Enums in java does not support inheritance, as @VGR use interfaces to somhow support polymorphism.

Comment: @STaefi I thought aboit it. It seems that Interfaces would not work well in my case -- the items have to contain numerous fields, and using getters for them in the default method implementations would be rather cumbersome.

Comment: @VGR in case of aggregation you talk about, how can the methods of the Parent instance have access to the fields of enumeration items? I can't imagine how this could be implemented. Well, I'll try to think more thoroughly.

Comment: I'm confused.  What are you trying to actually *accomplish*?  This design doesn't seem to be very clear.

Comment: @VGR Got it. I have a class that incapsulates all the functionality, an instance of it in each item, and use it like `ITEM.data().doWhateverNeed()` for all the enums I need.